# Does clickhouse offers any tool like red gate sql toolbelt

Tags: clickhouse

I would like to compare two clickhouse databases and generate an upgrade script which I can apply for out of date databases.

For SQL server I know tool called Red Gate toolbelt which does this job.

Is there any product which can do exactly same for clickhouse database

Answer (score 0):

all-in-one solution is not available yet,
you could try to use https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/